# Change drawer icon back to back arrow

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the new `DrawerLayout` to have side navigation. I'm using the drawer icon (the 'hamburger') like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_drawerlayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, 
            mDrawerLayout, 
            R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name, 
            R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

However, when I add a `Fragment` to the backstack, I want to display the back arrow again, so the user can navigate back to "home", and only then open the app drawer.

How can I reset the drawer icon to the back icon?
The arrow I want:

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292130/746347

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To disable and hide the DrawerToggle "Hamburger", just call

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell how to implement back action on click after mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false) ?

I am trying to go back to listview fragment from content detail fragment.
P.S: I can go to previous fragment using back button.

Comment: @adnanyousafch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-carat-when-using-fragme

Comment: So helpful, Thanks a alot!

Comment: I just want to change that hamburger icon and its back icon too. they're small and very close to the left.

Answer (score 2):

I created an interface for the hosting activity to update the view state of the hamburger menu.  For top level fragments I set the toggle to `true` and for fragments for which I want to display the up < arrow I set the toggle to `false`.

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void showDrawerToggle(boolean showDrawerToggle);
    }

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            this.mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mListener.showDrawerToggle(false);
    }
}
```

Then in my Activity ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public void showDrawerToggle(boolean showDrawerIndicator) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(showDrawerIndicator);
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I make this 'generic', so it applies to many classes like `SomeFragment`? Or does `MainActivity` have to implement each one individually?

Comment: @IanB, I think u should create someclass for example BaseFragment, implement that code, then extend every fragment that u want to use that interface with Base Fragment