# Disabling navigation drawer, toggling home-button/up-indicator in fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

### The setup

I have an activity whose contentView is an instance of a `DrawerLayout`, which has a navigation drawer with a drawer indicator displayed in the action bar. The activity contains a `Fragment`, let's call it `ListFragment`, which contains a list of options. When an option is clicked, I replace the `ListFragment` with a `DetailFragment`.

[image: Architecture of the application]

At this point, I would like to display an "up" navigation option instead of the navigation drawer indicator. I'm able to display the "up" icon if I disable the drawer indicator by calling `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`, but this only removes the drawer icon--it does not remove the functionality--that is, when I click the caret, the navigation drawer is still opened.

Additionally, in these subviews, I would like to disable the opening of the drawer by dragging from the edge of the screen. I have tried doing this by calling `setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` but it doesn't seem to have disabled this functionality.

I have tried extending the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class to prevent opening the drawer when the indicator is clicked--however, all that happens is that the overriding action (the "up" navigation) is performed, but the drawer **still opens**.

I have also implemented the steps in [Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-carat-when-using-fragme?rq=1) . It works insofar as displaying the caret goes, but despite overriding the up button functionality, the menu still opens (the app does navigate back--it just also opens the drawer).

### Question

So, long story short: is there any (preferably clean and elegant, but at this point I'll go with hacky) way to achieve these things when my layout root is a `DrawerLayout`:

1. Replace the drawer indicator with an "up" caret (tentatively doable via `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false))`
2. Prevent the drawer from opening when the caret is clicked, and instead override with my own "up" functionality
3. Prevent the drawer from opening when I drag from the edge of the screen.

### Edit

All right, it looks like if I both override `ActionBarDrawerToggle` AND `onOptionsItemSelected`, the menu does not open when I click the caret. But it still opens if I drag from the edge. Help!

Comment: Hi, i met the same problem. But I fixed it by setting a few options in ActionBarSherlock, and I think the same way can also be performed when using the stock ActionBar. So did you use any of these ActionBars at that time?

Comment: Yes, I was using the stock ActionBar.

Comment: What do you mean with: I ovverride ActionBarDrawerToggle? What methods did you override of it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a long time ago and I don't remember now. What issue are you encountering?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is only part of the solution that I arrived at, but it was quite hard to figure out this bug, so I'm leaving this here for posterity's sake.

This how I was defining the ListView for my navigation drawer:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Even after calling `setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` I was still able to slide the drawer open.

However, after changing the `layout_gravity` to `"start"` this problem seems to be resolved.

I was able to reproduce this issue in a sample, navigation-drawer-only app, so it does appear to be a reproducible issue not unique to my situation.

Comment: @Catherine Is the *"sample, navigation-drawer-only app"* available online?

Comment: No, but I probably have it knocking around and can upload it onto Github for you if you need it. By the way, a bunch of your edits were wrong--http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/dashes.asp and "insofar" is one word. :P

Comment: You made a pretty big problem solve so easily..
Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 34):

Short Code

```
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if ( isEnabled ) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        drawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

    }
    else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        drawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! 

I implemented this is my NavigationDrawerFragement generated by android studio. This allowed me to call it before switching fragments.

Comment: Very good, it helped me. The only problem is that for `onDrawerStateChanged` parameter should be one of the `DrawerLayout.STATE_*`. Thanks very much!

Comment: use this 

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }


    private void closeMenu() {
        if ( mDrawerLayout != null ) {
            closeDrawer();
        }
    }

Answer (score 12):

Building on sonida's answer. After calling setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false), onNavigateUp wasn't being called still. So, I just created a new onClickListener that called it:

```
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if ( isEnabled ) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

    }
    else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSupportNavigateUp();
            }
        });
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

also I think

```
drawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

has been depreciated, but it works fine without it.

Comment: I used `onBackPressed();` instead of `onSupportNavigateUp();` and this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable swipe and disable the actionbar home button:

Use the below code that builds on the code already given to disable swipe

```
  public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
        if ( isEnabled ) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        }
        else {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on answer by @sonida And after using the tweaks given by @luca992 and @jai.

I tried above suggested codes But the "up" or "Back" arrow in left side of action bar was just not showing up in my app. But luckily I was able to fix that.

I had to add this extra line of code in setNavigationDrawerState() [Ref: [android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) ]

> toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp);

I downloaded the drawable: ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp from [Material.io](https://material.io/icons/#ic_keyboard_backspace)

Here is the complete code:

MainActivity.java -> onCreate()

```
DrawerLayout drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Start: Code automatically generated by Android Studio
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    // End: Code automatically generated by Android Studio

    // I had to add this listener as the "back" arrow was totally unresponsive
    // Thanks to @luca992
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    // Start: Code automatically generated by Android Studio
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    // End: Code automatically generated by Android Studio

    // More custom code for other stuff
    // ...
}
```

MainActivity.java -> setNavigationDrawerState()

```
public void setNavigationDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
if ( isEnabled ) {
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();
}
else {
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    // the extra line of code goes here
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp);    

    toggle.syncState();
}
```

MainActivity.java -> onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java -> startFragment() [dummy function for example]

```
public void startFragment(){
    MyFrag myFrag = new MyFrag();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frag_container ,myFrag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
        .commit();
}
```

MyFrag.java --> onViewCreated()

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Say, using an implemented interface Make call to MainActivitiy's  setNavigationDrawerState() passing false
    // setNavigationDrawerState(false)

    // ...
}
```

MyFrag.java --> onDestroyView()

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    // Say, using an implemented interface Make call to MainActivitiy's setNavigationDrawerState() passing true 
    // setNavigationDrawerState(true)

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```