# How to replace Navigation Drawer menu with back arrow

Tags: android, android-fragments

After reading the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439320/disabling-navigation-drawer-toggling-home-button-up-indicator-in-fragments), I still can't figure out how to replace my `Navigation Drawer`'s menu with a simple back arrow that lets my user go back to the previous `Fragment`.

So far I'm able to hide the button to access the `Drawer` like such:

```
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if ( isEnabled ) {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);           
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();

    }
    else {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);           
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

How may I add the back arrow at its place?

Answer (score 1):

It's little late but I found one workaround.
I have used following in my activity

Firstly set drawer locked mode

```
 fullLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Then add below code to display back button

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then create drawer toggle and add drawer listner. Use below code.

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, fullLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    mToggle.syncState();
    mToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Backpress action
            finish();
        }
    });
    fullLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
```

Note - method `setDrawerListener` is deprecated. Modify above code as per your need.

Comment: can you tell how to restore drawer button and remove that lock mode ?

Comment: you can try setting fullLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED); and actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); I have not tried this code but i think it should work.

Comment: tried it but the back button disappears but the drawer button doesn't show back

Comment: have you set this line mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); you need to set true for drawer indicator.