# Up icon not showing in lower levels when Nav. Drawer is configured

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

OK, that was a clumsy title :(

Here's the description of the problem. There are two Activities: MainActivity & PreferenceActivity.

The MainActivity has drawer set up (per [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)) and working fine (behavior, three-line icon, everything).

The problem is that the **PreferenceActivity also shows the `R.drawable.ic_drawer`**, this is not as intended.

**Intended behavior** is to have **<** icon in the PreferenceActivity action bar.

The only changes to PreferenceActivity are:

- `onCreate()` I have added `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and
- I have overriden `onOptionsItemSelected()` (to handle `android.R.id.home` click to track some analytics).

I have tried suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-carat-when-using-fragme). Based on that, I have added `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);` in the `MainActivity.onResume()` and have added `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` in `MainActivity.onPause()`, but w/o any effect.

Ideas hove to solve this?

Could it be that the setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false) doesn't correctly revert the indicator because ActionBarSherlock defines the attribute for it (in its theme) as "homeAsUpIndicator" and not as "android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator" (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled%28boolean%29))?

Comment: I believe you need actionBar.setHomeAsUpEnabled(true) as well as  actionBar.setDisplayHomeUpAsEnabled

Comment: Sorry, but current versions of the API (standard: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html nor Compat: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) do not define such method.

Comment: Apologize, it was setHomeButtonEnabled(true) is what was meant.

Comment: No apology needed, @JaySnayder. The Home button was properly set, that was not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest edit of the question (regarding ABS) got me thinking.

Since I had problems with drower icon not moving, I have added this to my theme (extending ABS theme):

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_navigation_drawer</item>
```

Since actually this fixed the mentioned problem (of drawer icon not moving):

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

the attrib override in the theme was a leftover and was a root cause for **<** icon not showing on lower levels as it should, so **removing the "android:homeAsUpIndicator" override fixed my problem.**