# Android Navigation Drawer Show Up Indicator for Lower Level Fragments

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have some issues switching navigation drawer functionality to up functionality at **lower level fragment**. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme) to manage to show the up indicator. But when pressing the button, it'll open up the navigation drawer instead of going back to previous fragment. And I can't set action bar title in **EditUserFragment** to "Edit Profile".
I'm using the navigation drawer template available in Android Studio.

I have three levels:

1. **MainActivity** with navigation drawer that consists of Home and Profile items
2. **UserFragment** titled with "Profile" that has an option item that'll bring up **EditUserFragment**
3. **EditUserFragment** (lower level fragment) is triggered by **UserFragment**

---

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // this won't change the drawer indicator back
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    // this works
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    // Show the corresponding title on the action bar when clicked and open corresponding
    // fragments.
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_profile);
            fragment = new UserFragment();
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    Log.d("Title 2", getActionBar().getTitle().toString());
}
```

`onBackPressed` is working partially (commented in code) when I pressed back button on phone (not up button on action bar).

---

**UserFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_edit:
            drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            // Disable sliding from edge to open drawer
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new EditUserFragment())
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

**EditUserFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Edit Profile");
    Log.d("Title", getActivity().getActionBar().getTitle().toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Get item selected and deal with it
    Log.d("KEY: ", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.d("EditUserFragment", "I'm here");
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` works as expected that up caret is showing instead of drawer; though when tapping it, it's opening up drawer instead of going back to previous fragment. In addition, the code under `case android.R.id.home` is never executed.
And I try to set action bar title to "Edit Profile" from "Profile". The log shows me "Edit Profile", but the actual running app shows me "Profile" for some reason.

---

What I want to achieve is be able to go back to `UserFragment` from `EditUserFragment` by tapping the up indicator (right now the up indicator is opening up navigation drawer). And show correct title in `EditUserFragment`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of analyzing, I discovered that the problem is I am using the built-in navigation drawer activity when creating it. The built-in separate the tasks into two. `MainActivity` and `NavigationDrawerFragment`. Thus, the `drawerToggle` I have in `MainActivity` is not the same as the real one in `NavigationDrawerFragment`.

Oroginally, `MainActivty` calls `NavigationDrawerFragment` to setup all the things needed for navigation drawer. I **SOLVED** this by implementing navigation drawer in my `MainActivity`, so I'll have only one `drawerToggle`. Though, I still can't find the way to make it work if I have everything (the navigation drawer variables) in `NavigationDrawerFragment` rather than `MainActivity`. If anyone knows the answer to that, feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: Hi! I am implementing something similar in my app. I have a navigation drawer with three fragments and on one of that fragment I had a listview, when you click on a item on the listview it opens a third fragment (lower fragment) and I want to show now the up caret and disable the navigation drawer. I've trying this almost for two weeks with no success.. I did not use a built in navigation drawer activity and I don't have a navigationDrawerFragment. Can you help me please? :)

Comment: @neteot You need to have a public function in `MainActivity` to reset your action bar from your lower level fragments.
In the function, you'll do something like the following:
`mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

And when you want to show the caret, call the function from your fragment.

Comment: thanks! turns out that in this time I've implemented **Fragment Navigation Drawer** but still did not has the desire result. I've tried what you suggest me, but now on the lower level fragment it does not appear neither the hamburger icon nor up caret icon, and it is worst (turns out that I have to implement a action menu options for going back from the lower level to the listview) it just popUp the last fragment of the stack. But now in the listview also does not appear the hamburger icon :/ thank you for your answer I think I have to be very close to the solution