# Missing Up navigation icon after switching from ICS ActionBar to Lollipop Toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I have an activity with many fragments that uses action bar and navigation drawer. It has "home as up" enabled. I have implemented proper logic that only top level fragments show action bar drawer toggle icon, other fragments show up arrow. I achieved this by:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mDrawerList);
```

Now old v4 support library ActionBarDrawerToggle became deprecated. I've switched to v7 version together with new `Toolbar` to get Material Design look. After that when drawer is open "up" arrow is correctly displayed, but when the above-mentioned code is executed it disappears completely.

Is it a bug in support library or I have to do something different to show "up" arrow instead of drawer indicator?

Comment: the support library is as unhelpful, undocumented and problematic as it can right now, I'm having lots of problems with it. That said, try getActionBarCompat().displayHomeAsUpEnabled() or <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item> under <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried to get themed up indicator using `getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator ()` and set it after you disable the indicator?

Because when the indicator is disabled `ActionBarDrawerToggle` tries to set the previous indicator.

From `ActionBarDrawerToggle` source:

```
public void setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean enable) {
    if (enable != mDrawerIndicatorEnabled) {
        if (enable) {
            setActionBarUpIndicator((Drawable) mSlider,
                    mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START) ?
                            mCloseDrawerContentDescRes : mOpenDrawerContentDescRes);
        } else {
            setActionBarUpIndicator(mHomeAsUpIndicator, 0);
        }
        mDrawerIndicatorEnabled = enable;
    }
}
```

Edit:

As of deprecation of `ActionBarActivity`, you should use `getDrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator ()`

Comment: It helped to show the arrow but `onOptionsItemSelected` is not called when it is tapped. It seems like the problem is somewhere deeper...

Comment: Try to replace the toolbar again. Using setSupportActionBar()

Comment: That helped, but this is the ugliest ever hack I have seen!

Comment: Maybe just invalidating current `Toolbar`will work too.

Comment: invalidating current Toolbar doesn't work. And This toolbar thing make the code really ugly :(

Comment: this worked till now but recently had to update support lib to v 22.1.0 and the change of hamburger icon works but when you come back to previous fragment where you want to show navigation drawer the hamburger icon is shown but it still works as up . ie does not open nav drawer.  Any ideas??

Comment: @Ravi I have a simple yet elegant way of [dealing with the back issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30951016/1276636).

Answer (score 18):

Answer/comments of Nikola Despotoski and Andrey Novikov are perfectly correct but I want to mention that after toolbar was replaced with following code:

```
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

your activity will receive every onOptionsItemsSelected events even if you enable your drawer toogle again drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
So you need to handle this, I've ended with

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (drawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
                return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            } else {
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked till now but recently had to update support lib to v 22.1.0 and the change of hamburger icon works but when you come back to previous fragment where you want to show navigation drawer the hamburger icon is shown but it still works as up . ie does not open nav drawer. Any ideas??

Comment: @Ravi have you tried setting the up display based on backstack count? ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/19132453/2413303  )

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes i did  use this on backstack change the problem is the icon is appropriate . ie the hamburger icon but it does not open the navigation drawer anymore mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

Answer (score 2):

If you use AppCompatActivity, you can get the right drawer icon and back icon by

```
        if(homeUp)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

    }
    else
    {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Without need for getV7DrawerToggleDelegate :D

Comment: Thank you! Only this solution works in my case for AppCompat v7 and list of fragments