# Tool bar setNavigationOnClickListener breaks ActionbarDrawerToggle functionality

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I'm swapping out the action bar for the tool bar, and I nearly have every piece of the puzzle in place. My issue is specifically if I navigate 'up' and restore the navigation drawer, the drawer toggle button no longer works. I figured out if I set the drawer mode to unlocked I have the ability to swipe to open the drawer, but can't click to open the drawer.

So I load fragment A, drawer behaviour is fine, go down to fragment B and apply the up icon, hit up to go back to A, and the drawer won't open with a click any more.

Entering Fragment B:

```
Toolbar t = mHostingActivity.getToolbar();
        mHostingActivity.getDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mHostingActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        t.setNavigationIcon(mHostingActivity.getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
        t.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popBackStackToTop(mHostingActivity);
            }
        });

/**
 * Pop the back stack and hide the Up caret all the way to the top level of the {@link com.loylap.activities.MainActivity}
 *
 * @param activity our hosting activity
 */
public static void popBackStackToTop(MainActivity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        activity.getDrawerLayout().setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        activity.getDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The navigation drawer is set up just like the sample, maybe the old way of setting up the options is the issue? For example, I still have this in my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

EDIT:

Okay so I've narrowed down the issue to the setNavigationOnClickListener(). If I don't set this (and go up via back button) - the drawer behaves correctly. So now the question is how do I correctly allow the user to go 'up', and restore the click listener after to we do go up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I've figured out I was creating the wrong click listener. Instead of setNavigationOnClickListener(), I need [setToolbarNavigationClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setToolbarNavigationClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) :)

A subtle but important change, now the tool bar is behaving in partnership with the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle

```
/**
 * Create the Up caret for a lower level fragment {@link com.loylap.activities.MainActivity}
 *
 * @param activity our hosting activity
 */
public static void createUpButton(final MainActivity activity)
{
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = activity.getDrawerToggle();
    //Disables onClick toggle listener (onClick)
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popBackStackToTop(activity);
        }
    });

    Toolbar t = activity.getToolbar();
    t.setNavigationIcon(activity.getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
    activity.getDrawerLayout().setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a quick note to this, I've noticed onOptionsItemSelected is not fired in fragments, but seems fine for activities - where the standard android.R.id.home check can be made

Comment: Thanks. I just modified your solution into a [simpler one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30951016/1276636).

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was a matter of order, I needed to first set the toolbar and than set the on click listener. in this order:

```
       //works
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDrawer(view);
        }
    });
```

rather than this:

```
    //doesn't work
    myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDrawer(view);
        }
    });
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the solution of **Daniel Wilson** but you only have to do it once and it is all set.

In my `NavigationDrawer`'s `setUp()` (or you can do it anywhere you are initialising your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` instance), I write this code:

```
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    }
});
```

Now every time `android.id.home` is pressed and hamburger sign is not shown, the parent activity's `onBackPressed()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use:

```
     t.setNavigationIcon(mHostingActivity.getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
     t.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...
```

because it will break your normal navigation drawer behaviour.

Instead try something like this in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater):

```
mHostingActivity.getDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mHostingActivity.getDrawerToggle().setHomeAsUpIndicator(mHostingActivity.getV7DrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
```

and then in onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:  
        popBackStackToTop(mHostingActivity);
        return true;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

PS: don't forget to use setHasOptionsMenu(true); in your fragment onCreateView.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the input, that's actually the way it was originally. Several SO questions seem to have referenced the fact that R.id.home is no longer fired if you are using a tool bar which is a shame. I'm thinking now I need to remove any reference to the action bar drawer toggle and trigger drawer opening with a navigation click listener in the activity

Comment: Hi, that is strange, because in my project I'm using toolbar and android.R.id.home is normally fired when I click on the arrow icon. But I can see, that you have found another solution so maybe I will be inspired next time :)

Answer (score 0):

To animate we can use.

```
ValueAnimator drawerAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(Constants.HAMBURGER, Constants.BACK);
drawerAnimator.addUpdateListener(drawerAnimationUpdateListener);
drawerAnimator.setDuration(Constants.DRAWER_ANIMATION_DURATION);
drawerAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

pass action 0 for HAMBURGER icon and 1 for BACK.

```
public void updateNavigationDrawer(int action) {
    drawerArrowDrawable = actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable();
    if (action == Constants.BACK) {
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawerArrowDrawable);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //onBackPress();
            }
        });
       drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED););
    } else {
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    }
    if (drawerArrowDrawable.getProgress() != action) {
        if (action == Constants.BACK) {
            drawerAnimator.start();
        } else {
            drawerAnimator.reverse();
        }
    }
}
```