# Home button is not clickable

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Inside my `SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity`  I have `SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment`. When I try press home-buttion in toolbar it is not working. Here is my code

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settingsToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setupToolBar();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();

    }

  private void setupToolBar() {
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settingsToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.settings));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setFocusable(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried  to solve it in such way: remove `setNavigationOnClickListener` and add this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
             return true;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
    }
```

It does not help. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try removing the call to `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()`, it might over-ride the click event, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263643/tool-bar-setnavigationonclicklistener-breaks-actionbardrawertoggle-functionality

Answer (score 0):

add this line to config your getSupportActionBar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

use both code in your activity like below:

in your setupToolbar method:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Log.d("cek", "home selected");
                finish();
            }
        });
```

and in your onOptionsItemSelected method:

```
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: home button is not clickable

Comment: add this line to config your getSupportActionBar:
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: please add your SettingActivity layout xml file.