# Up Navigation in Fragments with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

I want to use a single activity called MainActivity which has a drawer layout and main content container(using FrameLayout). The drawer layout for now is just a normal ListView which has only two items for now. I have made two Fragments for each of those items. The first item is Home and the second is Saved. 
When the MainActivity onCreate() is called I replace the container with the HomeFragment and from there I can use the Drawer to Navigate to the SavedFragment.
The Navigation works perfectly and has no issues. 
The task which I want to achieve is that whenever I go to SavedFragment by clicking the second item on the Drawer, the Hamburger icon should change to back button/up button. 
I managed to change it by going through a lot of StackOverflow topics on the same issue, but I am not able to add click event on that. It doesn't listen for a click. I read some very good stuff on StackOverflow and expected that it would work for me as well, but maybe I am wrong somewhere in my code. So I am sharing the code over here:

MainActivity (Only Activity in the application) Code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
Fragment mFragment;
ArrayList<NavigationDataRecord> drawerRecord;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_left);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    drawerRecord = new ArrayList<NavigationDataRecord>();
    drawerRecord.add(new NavigationDataRecord(R.mipmap.ic_home_grey600_24dp, "Home"));
    drawerRecord.add(new NavigationDataRecord(R.mipmap.ic_save_grey600_24dp, "Saved"));
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, drawerRecord);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };


        mFragment = new HomeFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}




@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mFragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            mFragment = new SavedFragment();
            break;

        default:
           break;

    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);

}}
```

SavedFragment Code

```
public class SavedFragment extends Fragment {


List<SavedInformation> list;
RecyclerView cardView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_fragment, container, false);
    list = new ArrayList<SavedInformation>();
    makeCardList();
    cardView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    //cardView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    cardView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    SavedInformationAdapter adapter = new SavedInformationAdapter(list, getActivity());
    cardView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return view;
}

private void makeCardList() {
    DatabaseAdapter adapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
    Cursor cursor = adapter.getData();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        SavedInformation information = new SavedInformation();
        information.setUsername(cursor.getString(0));
        information.setDomainName(cursor.getString(1));
        information.setImageURL(cursor.getString(2));
        list.add(information);

    }
}}
```

I tried a few things on these, but had no luck so I am posting the clean version of the code on which I tried implementing solutions.

I am sure that those solutions were correct, but I am unable to understand Why those did not work for me.

I applied the solution given here: [Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme)

Comment: Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragments then to navigateUp you have to use in the MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How will the icon change to up icon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: It is a Toolbar which is the AppBar in my case. OnSupportNavigateUp() doesn't work for me. 
I hope you understood the task I want to achieve coz the link you shared is not about that.