# setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false) opens empty fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954026/2083818 answer to implement the hamburger into caret and back into hamburger icon, depending on where you are in the application. That is, if you open the navigation drawer, it should show an "up" caret, to close the navigation drawer. Also if you're on a lower fragment than the main one, it should it as well. Thing is, when I open the navigation drawer (clicking the hamburger icon) from the main fragment, toggleDrawingIndicator is called with argument false (which is obviously the desired behavior), but instead of opening the navigation fragment, it simply opens an empty fragment to replace the old fragment. This does not happen, when toggleDrawingIndicator is called with argument true.

Anyone has experienced this before?

Comment: that seems to be old. You should follow the new design pattern the drawer comes over the toolbar. http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Damn it. I'm pretty steep into the process of using it, and not really bothered to revert it. Hopefully there is still a fix for the problem though.