# Cannot listen clicks on up caret

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I've a single activity(MainActivity) which extends actionbaractivity and implements NavigationDrawer. I've setup the drawertoggle in the activity itself.

I'm creating new fragments from a fragment that was created by another fragment which is in turn created by the MainActivity. ( MainActivity -> HomeFragment ->AnotherFragment).

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, TitleSetter, NavigationDrawerEnabler{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), myToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.OncreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


        /*  This function is never called even if the Up caret button is pressed!!   */
     if (mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled() &&
                mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                /*This case doesn't occur*/
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_something);
                break;
            case 2:
                //fragment = new SomeotherFragment();
                //title = getString(R.string.title_somethings);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        enableNavigationDrawer(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void enableNavigationDrawer(boolean isEnabled) {
        if ( isEnabled ) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        }
        else {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TitleSetter) getActivity()).setTitle("Home");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab:
                ((NavigationDrawerEnabler) getActivity()).enableNavigationDrawer(false);
                Fragment newFragment = new NewWord();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                // Commit the transaction
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }

    }


}
```

AnotherFragment.java

```
public class NewWord extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Get item selected and deal with it
        /*Not even this*/
        Log.d("KEY: ", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
        /* Doesn't execute*/
                Log.d("Fragment", "I'm here");
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_word, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((TitleSetter) activity).setTitle("Text");
    }
```

Also the drawer layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.calgen.wordbook.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer" />
```

And menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I actually referred this tutorial to setup navigation drawer fragment : [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/).

I also referred similar questions answered here on stackoverflow :

1.[Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme?lq=1)

2.My problem is similiar to this : [Android Navigation Drawer Show Up Indicator for Lower Level Fragments](http://Android%20Navigation%20Drawer%20Show%20Up%20Indicator%20for%20Lower%20Level%20Fragments).
- I couldn't comment here as i do not have 50 reps. I implemented what was exactly told in the comments.

But still clicking on the up caret doesn't run the function onOptionItemSelected, even though i've homebutton enabled.!

I'm now adding my custom styles.xml, may be some error in this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/nav_background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Also the custom toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Seems like I've to work this out on my own.

Comment: The question really is not clear. You do not have any code in `onOptionsItemSelected`. You simply have a comment "does nothing" in the switch case.

Comment: I purposefully removed the code from there to make the question shorter. When i click the up-caret button, `onOptionItemSelected` is never called. @Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED FINALLY**

I figured out the problem, it is due to the custom toolbar that I used. When a custom toolbar is set up, we also have to set a listener on the `up caret` using the method called `drawertoggler.setNaviagtionOnClickListener`

In the onCreate() method of the activity we need to add the following code:

```
drawertoggler.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    });
```

Other cases like OnBackPressed can be handled by setting a `OnStackChangeListener` in the activity and make necessary changes. It is clearly explained here :[@riwnodennyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954026/3225001).

Comment: Ok.Let me try out and get back to you.Thank you.