# Left Menu Icon on Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

How to Change the left side menu icon on the Action Bar ? I have created this using Navigation Drawer Fragment in Android Studio. Now an Arrow pointing left is displayed "<-" but i need to display the = icon. Where should i change this ?

Comment: Have you added any fragment  backstack ?

Comment: when you say = icon. did u mean sandwich icon  ??

Comment: no fragment backstage and yes the sandwich icon.

Comment: I suggest you follow the built in navigation drawer project in Android Studio when you create a new project

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9265774/4224337

Answer (score 1):

You could use this format for your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.CUSTOM_ICON, // Navigation menu toggle icon
    R.string.DRAWER_OPEN, // Navigation drawer open description
    R.string.DRAWER_CLOSE // Navigation drawer close description
    )
```

Change your drawable and make sure it is the same name as the one in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the indicator you've to use:

```
public void toogleDrawer(boolean value){
  mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!value);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(value);
}
```

Please post the complete code relating to your drawer fragment, and action bar setup(if any) and also the relevant layouts. You've to research around a bit before asking the question. Check this question here : [Cannot listen clicks on up caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154198/cannot-listen-clicks-on-up-caret)

Everyone can provide specific answers to your problem if you add more content to it.

Comment: he didn't ask what you have posted.! ;)