# Navigation drawer intersept home event

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using drawer layout as below. So my fragments are attached to frame layout below toolbar. When I show fragment I change home button from humburger to arrow with:

```
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(b);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(show);
```

The problem is - when I click arrow button, there is no event for onOptionsItemSelected in activity or in fragment. If i donw use `drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(b);` arrow button will open the navigation drawer. How to fix such behaviour?

Layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/bg_drawer"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="138dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_logo" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/drawer_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
            android:paddingLeft="24dip"
            android:paddingRight="24dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Navigation drawer set up

```
public void setUpNavigationDrawer(){
        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 3 / 4;
        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) navigationHolder.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        navigationHolder.setLayoutParams(params);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        ){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                        mContext
                    );
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }


            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset){
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }


            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if(needToChangePage){
                    onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(
                        (int) drawerView.getTag()
                    );
                }
                needToChangePage = false;

            }
        };

        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationHolder);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.post(
            new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    drawerToggle.syncState();
                }
            }
        );
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }
```

[Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme) tried approach from here, but with same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen clicks on android.R.id.home when navigation drawer is set its nessesary to add toolbar listener

```
drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
            }
        );
```

this listener will fier only if `drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`