# Using Fragments recover Home/Drawer Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

I have an app with a main activity which loads a navigation drawer, and a pair of fragments that load in that activity ... 
In the navigation drawer I have 4 options A, B, C and D ... the first one loads FragmentA on my activity and the last 3 load FragmentB ..

**FragmentA** displays a list of elements and, upon selecting one of these elements **FragmentB** is used to load its content... I want to change the home (hamburger/drawer) icon on *FragmentB* for the up icon when initiating from *FragmentA* (and change the corresponding behavior to make a popstack on select).. I have no problem with this using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, but since all this is occurring inside one activity if I then select one other option (say B) from the navigation drawer the up icon will still be showing (it its also showing on the popped fragment)... 
if I use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` all this do is hide the home/up button from the toolbar, I need to recover the home button and make sure this will be shown when *FragmentB* is initiated from the drawer menu ...

Does this problem ring a bell to anyone? or am I just using fragments the wrong way? .. any advice will be appreciated

**EDIT**
this is more or less what I have in code

In Main Activity .. as the onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) for the drawer I have a something like this ...

```
switch(optionNumber) {
            case 0:
                  fragment = FragmentA.newInstance(optionNumber);
                break;
            default:
                  fragment = FragmentB.newInstance(optionNumber);
                break;
        }
        Fragment frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("current_fragment");
        if (frag != null && frag.getClass() == FolderFragment.class){
            ((FolderFragment)frag).resetScroll();
        }

        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment, "current_fragment").commit();
```

which selects the fragment to load according to the option selected..

In FragmentA I'm calling FragmentB with this ..

```
 FragmentB fFragment = FragmentB.newInstance(position);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("filter", "something"); fFragment.setArguments(args);

    mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flContent, fFragment, "current_fragment")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Preserving the fragment in the stack

And in fragmentB inside onResume() function I got something like...

```
String filter = getArguments().getString("filter", null);


    if (type != null) {
        mActivity.setTitle(title);
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }else {
        /*mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_menu);*/
    }
```

So When I'm creating fragmentB I check for arguments and see if it comes from fragmentA or not ( I could also check the fragmentmanager backstack and see if there's something)... there I just change the drawer icon with setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true) ... leaving the back arrow, if I return to FragmentA (via onBackPressed()) FragmentA shows the arrow and I need it to show the original drawer icon ... the same happens if I select an option from the drawer menu ... 
Does this gives more clarity to my issue ?... I have some commented code there because it doesn't work .. if I activate the line with setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false).. the icon just disappears from the activity (which is the intended result of the function as far as I know)...

Comment: Please add your source-code for better understanding

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like your starting FragB from two places and one place will change drawer icon only one way and the other needs to change it two ways. So when starting FragB from the swipe menu just detect the way that is needed and then change it accordingly.

Comment: @SeseSchneider there you go ...

Comment: @CmosBattery correct .. but how exactly do I change it back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I finally found this post

> [Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme)

I guess that when involving a Drawer in the interface you might need to handle this issue with that component... this post gave me the answer.
Particular notice to the last comment  by Wolfram Rittmeyer