# Remove Navigation Drawer and want to show action bar home button instead of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Home page should have navigation drawer Other page don't have navigation drawer

Show up caret -> like this

Home page view look like

[see here for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ako4x.png)

And the `fragment` view looks like this:

[see here for details Navigation drawer menu items selection snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr2rO.png)

Developing app with `navigation drawer` My home page having navigation drawer And i want to hide navigation drawer and show action bar home button `setHomeAsUpEnabled = true` instead of navigation drawer.

How can i achieve this logic onto my app?

Please let me know if any one know about this??

Comment: instead of fragment use activity and use custom toolbar with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme)

Answer (score 0):

to enable the Home back button  use the below code.

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I check with this one fragment working properly but Issue is the other fragments having navigation drawer menu And how to handle this for all fragmets?

Answer (score 0):

create custome toolbar by this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@mipmap/top_bar_bg"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

put this in activity

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

put this in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            >
```

replace your current activity with `android:name` and
replace your parent activity with `android:parentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

use this in fragment onCreateView or onResume `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);` that will hide hamburger and show de back button