# How to show and make the HomeAsUpEnabled functional when you use a appDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I found out, that I can turn on the back arrow with

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but when I click on the arrow the drawer opens instead of going to the first Fragment.

How can I turn off the `AppDrawer` inside a `Fragment` and turning it on again when in first `Fragment`?

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

With the following lines of code when you *back press first time then if your drawer opened*  then first it will close then on second back press you will go on previous activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {//this is check drower is open or not
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();//or you can redirect to the another activity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but it's not quite what i had in mind. Beside I'm not sure if a user would sense this behavier.
Isn't there a way to turn of the Drawer while on a specifiy Fragment?