# onSupportNavigateUp() not called

Tags: android

I'm developing an app with ActionBars which supports Gingerbread and up. So basically I'm using the support library and extending

> ActionBarActivity

for all my activities. Everything works well except for the

> [onSupportNavigateUp()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportNavigateUp%28%29)

method. It just does not get called as stated in the documentation.

> This method is called whenever the user chooses to navigate Up within
>   your application's activity hierarchy from the action bar.

This is quite easy but I haven't been able to figure out why it does not work as expected nor Googling helped. Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you enable the up button `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: It's actually `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` for me and yes, it is called on `onCreate()`

Comment: OK I just noticed that this gets called properly on my Nexus One running Android 2.3 but not on any device above 4.0. O_@

Answer (score 41):

if you override `onOptionsItemSelected`, then `onSupportNavigateUp` will not be called.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // handle ⬅️ button here 
                break;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the case if you return `true` otherwise `onSupportNavigateUp ` will be called.

Answer (score 12):

As said before, if you override `OnOptionsItemSelected`, `OnSupportNavigateUp` will not be called. you can make sure it gets called by adding a default: case inside the `OnOptionsItemSelected` like so:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.something:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,someActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` will make sure `OnSupportNavigateUp` is called. This is in case you don't want the case dealt inside your `OnOptionsItemSelected`

Answer (score 9):

Have you set in your Manifest.xml file the parent activity? If yes, it won't be called. @see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportNavigateUp()

Comment: Hey @Estornino thanks for the reply. This question was posted such a long time ago and sticking to the solution (or just a fix) I have mentioned above has worked so far for me. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: I was having the same issue and didn't shaw the date of the question. :(

Answer (score 3):

Who knew... `onSupportNavigateUp()` works only on 4.0 and above. For below `onNavigateUp()` is called.

Comment: I cannot confirm that. `onSupportNavigateUp()` is called for me on an API 10 emulator as well as an API 18 device, just as it should. So either you use an older / buggy version of the `ActionBarCompat` library or something else is going on.

Comment: When using the `ActionBarActivity`,  `onSupportNavigateUp()` is called on all API levels.

Answer (score 3):

It is also important to return true from onCreateOptionsMenu(), I have this set to false as I have custom menu but then onOptionsItemSelected() has not been called!

So use:

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }
```

And then

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_share -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So actually when you override `onOptionsItemSelected` you should return `false` by default for the `onSupportNavigateUp` method to be called. See below

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_print -> {
            doSomething()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem **onSupportNavigateUp** and **onOptionsItemSelected** was not calling

I need to prevent backPress on child fragments so I override setNavigationOnClickListener in toolbar

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {

       if(childFragmentHandleBackPressed()){
          NavigationUI.navigateUp(
            navController,
            AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
        )
       }
    }
```

or you can use **navController.navigateUp()** if you don't want to open navigation drawer menu on **start/root fragment**

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this line in onCreate() method

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

along with on `onSupportNavigateUp()` method