# Prevent Fragments from being added multiple times to back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack

I'm currently laying out the basics for an application I'm going to develop. There is an action bar with a couple of menu items assigned to it. Each menu item has its own fragment, which needs to be displayed in the main activity. However, I want the "up" affordance of the action bar to appear when any fragment but the MainFragment itself is being displayed.

My current approach is based upon the solution presented at [actionbar up navigation with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments) and looks something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.action_identities) {
        fragment = new IdentitiesFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_history) {
        fragment = new HistoryFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        fragment = new AboutFragment();
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged()
{
    displayHomeAsUp();
}

private void displayHomeAsUp()
{
    int stackCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(stackCount > 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp()
{
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

This works great, but there is a problem when pressing the same menu item multiple times, because a new instance of the fragment will be put on the back stack each time. What is the best way to prevent this from happening? Obviously I could check whether the currently displayed fragment is the one being requested, but this results in a lot of checks and is kind of redundant. Another way might be transaction tags, but I'm not sure as to whether this would result in cleaner code.

What is the best way to do this? Isn't this a generic problem, or is the way I want the app to "behave" wrong? Because personally I do like the "up" function of the action bar quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the selected menu id as `Integer` and next time , you can check the selected id with the previous one ,and add the fragment only if the id is different

```
private int previousSelectedId = 0;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if(previousSelectedId == id) {
        return true;   
   }else{
         previousSelectedId = id;
        // add the fragment
   }
}
```

Another approach is , you can check the `instance` of the already existing `Fragment` and replace only if it doesn't exist.

```
 Fragment addedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
 if (addedFragment != null &&
        !addedFragment.getClass().isInstance(fragment)) {
        // replace the fragment here
        return true;
    }
```

`addedFragment` is the instance of already added fragment. `fragment` is the instance based on your menu item selected.

Note: I don't really recommend to use `getClass()` or `isInstance`. But to make a simple check this it what i can suggest.

Comment: What is the reason you wouldn't suggest `getClass()` and/or `isInstance()`? It seems that you guys don't have the problem I outlined above, so how are you handling the action bar's up affordance? I'm in an early state of my project, so I'm happy to adjust accordingly, if you give me good reasons to ;).

Comment: logically you can use getClass and isInstance. but theoretical i am in understanding its a bad design :)

Comment: You can just remember the last selected menu id and add the fragment only if selected id is different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but saving the previously selected item as integer might get ugly once fragments are accessible through other means and not just through the option menu itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved this issue
Attach a tag at every fragment and before adding any fragment in back-stack check is it already available in stack?
Sample Code

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String FRAGMENT_TAG) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) == null) {
        if (AppConstants.DEBUG) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside Fragment add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by boolean its simple and clean...

lets say you have 4 fragments so it needs 4 boolean checks each time you pressed one of the fragment its corresponding boolean will be true and the next time you press it it wont get add to the fragment until you backstack it...

```
if (identity == true && id == R.id.action_identities) {
    fragment = new IdentitiesFragment();
    identity = true;
} else if (history == true && id == R.id.action_history) {
    fragment = new HistoryFragment();
    history = true;
} else if (setting == true && id == R.id.action_settings) {
    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    setting = true;
} else if (about == true && id == R.id.action_about) {
    fragment = new AboutFragment();
    about = true;
}
```

Comment: It's certainly possible to solve it like that, but to be honest I don't consider this as a clean solution, because it is kind of redundant.

Comment: @KarolBabioch then your only choice is through tagging the fragment