# Implementing back button in android fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-button

I'm using this tutorial to implement facebook login etc.

[Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate)

I have added new fragment in this to show list of friends. Now when I press back button on my newly added fragment it takes me to the SPLASH fragment, I want same behaviour on back button on action bar. Means when I'm on my new fragment it shows me a back button on action bar. And pressing that back button takes me back to the SPLASH screen.

[image]

```
private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Saw that already but no answered is selected as answer there, so confused

Answer (score -1):

i got this code on stackoverflow after searching hard hope this may help you

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// in on Create()
```

search for code `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`
and edit it in this way

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // change your behaviour here
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourclass.class);// i started new activity here
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
  }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: no you got it wrong, I want to get the same behaviour on pressing back button on action bar. Which I'm getting on pressing back button on android.

Comment: This is for activity i want it for fragments.

Comment: I have added a picture also. In my question

Comment: sorry but i cant see pictures, they are blocked by admins in our computers

Comment: i found this example useful for your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments

Comment: can i know the reason for downvoting.