# Hide Toolbar Up Button in certain page of WebViewClient

Tags: android, android-webview, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement material design for my `WebViewClient`. The `WebViewClient` opens `index.html` saved in my asset. What I want to achieve is when the home page, `index.html` is opened, there shouldn't be a "up button". "Up button" should only be shown when I click on the link in `index.html`. I have tried

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But apparently, this show "up button" for all of the pages. How to hide the "up button" for my homepage, `index.html`?

Comment: instead of true it should be false

Comment: After I changed it to `false`, the "up button" is hidden for all of my HTML pages. I just want to hide the "up button" for `index.html` only.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments

Comment: I am sorry, I am doing with `WebView` but not fragment. Anyway, I have solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding this under `onPageFinished` in my `WebViewClient`

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equals("file:///android_asset/index.html")) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```