# Action bar with back arrow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making an app and I want to put an action bar with a back arrow in a fragment.
So, I already have the fragment with the action bar but don't know how to put the back arrow on it. 
Can you help me please?
Thank you,
Guilherme
[This is the fragment with an action bar tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJKwD.jpg)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments answer

Answer (score 3):

Add following line in your fragment if you want to show the back button from the fragment : 
 `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

It would be better that along with doing this. You add the parent of the activity in the manifest file to make sure that parent activity is opened when back arrow is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I have some thing like this for back button in toolbar instead of action bar.

In `activity_main.xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.wolfmatrix.dummy.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTextId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backButtonIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `styles.xml`: use theme => `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

In `ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml`, use this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
    android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
```

And now, toolbar has the back icon too.

Comment: when you say "In styles.xml: use theme => Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", you have to create a new style tag, right?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use `ToolBar` instead of `ActionBar`, you have to replace the default one by `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` .

Comment: It's like this: `<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

Implement OnBackStackChangedListener and add this code to your Fragment Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Listen for changes in the back stack
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    //Handle when activity is recreated like on orientation Change
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(){
   //Enable Up button only  if there are entries in the back stack
   boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canback);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    //This method is called when the up button is pressed. Just the pop back stack.
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your onCreate in the top

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

and add a function to the activity

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add below line after setcontentview()

```
 //by doin that Back arrow will appear
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Create following overridden method after onCreate().

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```