# How to make home button act as back button?

Tags: android, button, back-stack

I have two activities.One of them has Fragment.
    From this fragment I can go to another activity, but by clicking the button "home" it goes to previous activity instead of going to the **fragment** of the previous activity.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOE1v.jpg)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_closet);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [actionbar up navigation with fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments)

Answer (score 2):

Refere below code :

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override below method :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v){
      onBackPressed()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want same behavior as of `back` button you should use `onBackPressed();`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```