# Show an Alert on clicking Up button of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show an `Alert Dialog` when the user clicks on the up button of ActionBar. I have implemented `onBackPressed()` already. What I want to do now is trigger same action as for pressing `Back` button when user clicks the `Up` button from ActionBar.

I tried using `onNavigateUp()`. However, it just returns me to the parent activity without showing the Alert Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165609/) you can override **onOptionsItemSelected**  to detect action

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
       //enter your code here

        return true;
    }
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

try it

Comment: It works. Only change required is `return true` instead of `break` at the end of `case` block.

Comment: @dkhost07 \\ that's great