# How to save state of dynamic Radiobuttons in Fragments

Tags: android

How to save the state of dynamically generated radiobuttons in Fragment? When I move from one view to another i am loosing the values selected in previous view. Thanks in advance

Below is my working code:

LayoutFragment.java

```
public class LayoutFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    private String[] application = { "Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5", "Country6", "Country7", "Country8" };                     
    private String[] device = { "Country9", "Country10", "Country11", "Country12", "Country13", "Country14", "Country15", "Country16" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;
    Context thiscontext;

    static LayoutFragment init(int val) {
        LayoutFragment truitonFrag = new LayoutFragment();
        // Supply val input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        truitonFrag.setArguments(args);
        return truitonFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        Button myButton = (Button) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        thiscontext,
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 /*Iterator it = list.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("Data is"+ it.next());
                 }*/



            }
        });


        //Draw Radiobuttons

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);


        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button1.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                //Add to list
                                /*View v = radioGroup1.getChildAt(i);
                                if(v instanceof  RadioButton){
                                      if(((RadioButton) v).isChecked()){
                                      list.add((RadioButton) v);
                                }}*/

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button2.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                //Add to list
                                /*View v2 = radioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                if(v2 instanceof  RadioButton){
                                      if(((RadioButton) v2).isChecked()){
                                      list.add((RadioButton) v2);
                                }}*/

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        return layoutView;
    }

}
```

Comment: use SharedPreference to save and retrieve values.

Comment: @Rah - Not ideal I guess because I can have n number of sliding views in fragment iterating same layout.

Comment: Because android has its own GarbageCollector. so, u cannot control the destroying of previous object, one more thing you can do is send values as parameters.

Comment: put your fragments in backstack and retrieve them when needed

Comment: @Shahzeb - Do you have an example code ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack

Comment: @Shahzeb - Bit complicated, any easy implementation?