# Removing a Fragment from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an `Activity` that creates a `Fragment` and then this `Fragment` creates another `Fragment`:

**Activity -> Fragment1 -> Fragment2**

I am now in `Fragment2` and I'd like to go back to `Fragment1` by clicking on a button.

In my `OnClickListener` of my `button` I have:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment2.this).commit();
```

This brings me to the `Activity`. Is there actually a way to just remove `Fragment2` and go to `Fragment1`?

Thank you in advance for your time, I could not find any suitable info online!

Comment: You can use getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack() instead of removing the fragment

Comment: By using `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()` I get the same result, going back to activity

Comment: I use `replace()`, by using `add()` would I be able to pop?

Comment: refer to this post for mode clarifications : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AhmedAbidi has a nice insight to your problem and yes, implementing `popBackStack` properly may solve your problem. But anyway, I would like to suggest a different approach to handle this type of situations.

Write two public functions in your `Activity` to switch between your fragments.

```
public void switchToFragment1() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment1()).commit();
}

public void switchToFragment2() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment2()).commit();
}
```

Now from the button click in your `Fragment1` you might launch the `Fragment2` via,

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragment2();
```

And the same thing while switching to `Fragment1`

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragment1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more code for clarity.

Is Fragment1 adding Fragment2 via getSupportFragmentManager() or getChildFragmentManager()? Presumably it appears you are doing the former, and if so, you are incorrectly using the Fragment API. Fragments are not supposed to know about each other, per [Android's Fragment Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

You should therefore implement the appropriate listeners to communicate from Fragment1 to Activity, which can then decide where/when to add Fragment2 -- then properly utilize the back stack functionality of `getSupportFragmentManager().addToBackStack()`... with `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()`. See [Android Documentation on Back Navigation for Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) for further explanation.