# Remove a fragment on button click which is inside the fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a Relative layout and an ok button in mainActivity. On ok button click, a fragment will be added to this Relative layout. This Fragment has a cancel button.I want it to close that fragment on cancel button click.

```
public class filter_Fragment extends Fragment {

Button cancel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter_,container, false);

        cancel=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
            //Close fragment page. Return to mainActivity
         }
        });

  return rootView;
}
```

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: I have a cancel button inside the  fragment when i click on it ,i want it to dismiss the fragment and go back to main ativity.

Comment: Ok. Update your question with your code also.

Comment: Please try to explore this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127315/removing-a-fragment-from-a-fragment

Comment: Thank you .But it's not working. I tried following code also ...      cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Fragment fragment= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layoutchange);
                fragmentTransaction=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

Comment: It worked fine .but getting    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference...  And app crashed

Comment: Please let me know your main activity contains any fragment?I mean your home fragment require any fragment? If so you need to replace  with new fragment and if not you can call  startActivity(new Intent(...

Comment: I have a Relative layout  and an ok button in mainActivity. On ok button click,  a fragment will be added to this Relative layout. This Fragment  has a cancel button.I want it to close that fragment on cancel button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: or `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()` depends on what Fragment you use `android.app.Fragment` or `android.supportv4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Thank you.But its not working.No change on button click

Comment: @stanwyck can you post the code of MainActivity and the Fragment from where you are calling this fragment?

Answer (score -1):

You better to close fragment contained activity on clicking close button in that fragment like below

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Thank you. But this closes the application.I just need to close the fragment and go back to main activity on cancel button click.