# How to manage backstack of more than one fragments properly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have two fragments in my activity. In the first fragment, I display the titles, when I click the titles subtitles appear. In the second fragment, I display the content of the related topic, user can navigate a different page in this fragment. When I put the fragments to backstack, and retrieve the previous backstack record, I retrieve the wrong fragment's backstack record.

I want to navigate forward and backward in both fragments and manage the backstack properly. I use a single backstack for both fragments. How to manage backstack of two fragments properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Fragments backStack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack)

Comment: Show how you are adding the fragments to the backstack and how you are retrieving the previous backstack record. Without code we're not able to help out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists