# Using back button to go back to main activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I have created fragments in app drawer and now when I am pressing the back button on a fragment, it is closing the application.

There is already one existing onKeyDown in the webView of Main activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

For the onBackPressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Fragment Impementation method,

```
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("close");
        ft.commit();




    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: Show us your implementation of fragments.

Comment: Can you tell how exactly you are adding your `fragments` when you click on your drawer item?

Comment: if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            ft.commit();




        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

Answer (score 3):

When you add a fragment to some container or inflate it using xml, it is not added to the backstack and so, when 'onBackPressed' occurs it throws the last activity from the backstack- which is the activity hosting the fragment and thus exiting the application.
I think this post:
[Android: Fragments backStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack)

can help you, it explains how to add the fragment transaction to the backstack:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment transaction name, not required");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but this didn't work for me.. I have reposted the question with my fragment implementation...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in following way

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            //that means your stack is empty and you want to close activity
            finish();
        } else {
            // pop the backstack here
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont add the fragments to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//your code
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("your_tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you evoke a fragment add it to stack like this

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment");
```

and then in onBackPress pop it from stack like this

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("fragment", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```