# How to remove process from processor in android application

Tags: android-fragments

I have created one android app. In that i have Main Activity and in Main Activity i have sliding drawer. At first load my Home fragment will show and by click on home fragment's list will added another fragment so that i can see drawer in every screen so basically my whole app is in fragment.

Now issue is when i go to the 15 to 17 screen from Home fragment to sub fragment i got hang issue and i have found in android monitor that my app occupy 50% processor so i want to remove process from that processor what should i do?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use the property `addToBackstack()` for [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack)

Comment: @ Nazim i have already used this addToBackstack() property and in fact all my pervious fragment is in back stack