# Prevent fragment from recreating every time bottomnavigation tab is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm using BottomNavigationView in android to make a application just like Instagram. I'm using fragments with the navigationTabs. App have 5 tabs initialy I've set the middle tab as active tab and loads it once the app start. when i click on any other tab a network call is made and data is loaded. Now when i press on back button or click on the last tab again(which was loaded on startup) the fragment is recreated and the network call is made to load the same data. I want to show the previous fragments with same data without recreating.

I've tried using

`transaction.add(container,fragment);`

but to no avail.

my code on tab click

```
 if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_OverView && _current != R.id.nav_OverView) {
      Overview _overView = new Overview(); 
     _fragmentTransaction.hide(_currentFragment);
     _fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
     _fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_base_drawer, _overView);
     _fragmentTransaction.commit();
     _current = R.id.nav_OverView;
      viewIsAtHome = true;
     }
```

I know using remove and add is same as using replace.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354885/android-fragments-backstack). Or if this wont work for you use a singleton class to save data on first load, and use it after it .

Comment: post your `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` code, you're probably creating your fragment in it

Comment: @marmor updated... check now

Answer (score 1):

> Before creating the view you can check if the view is already created or not, the below code helps fragment recreating problem.

```
View view;

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

if (view == null) 

  {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
        init(view);
  }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `_overview` into a class field (instead of a local variable), and change your listener code to this:

Also, use [`replace`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) instead of `hide`+`add`, this will prevent `Fragment already added` errors.

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling **remove(Fragment)** for **all currently
>   added fragments** that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   **add(int, Fragment, String)** with the same arguments given here.

See example:

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_OverView && _current != R.id.nav_OverView) {
      if (_overView == null) {
          _overView = new Overview(); 
      }
     _fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
     _fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_base_drawer, _overView);
     _fragmentTransaction.commit();
     _current = R.id.nav_OverView;
     viewIsAtHome = true;
}
```

Comment: Fragment already added: fragmentName.. getting this error when try to go back to the previous fragment. Good point though pointing out about the class field, i was totally missing that.

Comment: yeah, instead of re-adding the fragment, you should remove the one hiding it

Comment: how exactly? Please make the edit. appreciate your help. how to check if the fragment is already loaded or its first run? if its already loaded calling the hide on last fragment will popup the second last fragment i think and not the required like if i open 1 2 3 4 5 and then open 2 by calling hide on 5, will it hide all 5 4 3 or just last one?