# Implementing back navigation in action bar in nested fragments with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer as main activity.On click of one of its item ,
 a fragment is added(as in this item its a list with custom list adap. ).[Fragment 1]
 Now on click on one of those items another fragment is replaced over it  and it displays the details.[Fragment 2]

Now when i click back button , application is destroyed . I need to go on 1 st fragment on back button 
clicked.How do i do that . Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you should just make sure to add the transaction to the backstack, but without any code it's a little hard to tell what you're currently doing. That is, what *"replaced over it"* really means.

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Fragment f2= new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f2);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);//null is optional you could replace with string-
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Ok it works .Thanks. how do i get left arrow in nav bar left in 2nd fragment , for navigation .

Comment: Use activity.actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); when you have launched second fragment.

Comment: this is the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) based on @HarshaVardhan answer

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are a part of an Activity. onBackPressed() works differenly for fragments. You must be applying onBackPressed() on the Activity. Check here for how to do it in fragments : [Using onBackPressed() in Android Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190047/using-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)