# using switch statement to handle onBackPressed() in fragments

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, onbackpressed

i am trying to handle the onBackPressed diferently for every fragment. for this i want to use a switch statement with cases dependedn on the fragment that is currently showing.
in my Main i have. but dont know what to use in the switchstatement.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
switch(........){
        case (1):
        Fragment1.onBackPressed();
        case (2):
        Fragment2.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

in my fragments:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    //My created method
    public static void onBackPressed()
    {
        // make it do what you want.
    }
}
```

so my question, how can i use a switchstament where de cases are depended on what fragment is showing at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use such switch in single `onBackpressed` of activity but you can get the key event of each fragment object and do like this,

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //Don't miss this line
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
           //Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Comment: hello, from what i have found/heard so far is that this wil not work when using for example edittext, of wich i have multiple. cause that will get focus

Comment: hey, i found a way to make this work, hoever this requires me to handle the event for every edit textfield seperatly, wich doesnt really seem like the best method.

Comment: no but when u are inside an edittext it gets focus and will not do the keyevent of the fragment

Comment: But the back key and clear key of soft keyboard are different.. Are you sure keyevent won't work when we are focused inside edittext ?

Comment: regretably i am, atm i am handeling the seperate with

`editName.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    backButton.toClientsFragment();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });`

this does work, but probably isnt the best way

Comment: Then you can implement OnKeyListener in Fragment or Activity

Comment: hmm, that wont work either, inside fragment for the reason we just discussed. in activity its not posible cause i have  mupltiple fragments handled by same activity, and all fragment need to handle onbackpressed in a seperate way. i was thinking of in the activity aswel with switch, but cant find a way to it like that

Comment: Have you tried addOnBackStackChangedListener as showin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190047/using-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

In on `onBackPressed()`. You can check current visible `Fragment`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(yourFragment1.isVisible()) {
           ...
        }else if(yourFragment2.isVisible(){
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, this does not seem to work, its never doing one if the if isVisible().