# How to Handle back button for Fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like handle back button in my application i have used fragment class in whole application .So when i would like to come back to base activity,it throw out application,Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments

Answer (score -3):

You just need to override the onBackPressed method on your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Put your logic here :)    
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I dont understand what you want to do, but if you want to implement your own code in the back button this is how you do it.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
// your code
    }
```

If you do nothing, then nothing will happen on a back press.

Edit: perhaps the above is not at all what you want, I've some difficulties understanding you. However, if you properly want to understand activities and how they are managed / created this is a must read. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html