# Calling AlertDialog.Builder in Java For Android Fragment When Back Button Is Pressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a simple application (really!) that displays a list and then displays the details of an item on the list based on the user's choice. I do this using Fragments. The details portion is a Fragment which has an `EditText` in it. Currently, if the user types in the `EditText` and clicks on the Save button, an `AlertDialog.Builder` pops up asking her if she wants to save. If she chooses yes, the text is saved to a database. I want the same thing to happen if the user hits the back button. In my class that extends `FragmentActivity`, I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_stitchdetail);
    frag.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return false;
}
```

In my class that extends `Fragment` (the details portion), I have:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getRepeatCount() == 0
            && Edited) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I'm not sure where to put the code that will call the `AlertDialog.Builder`. I want to put it in the `Fragment` class because the code needs to get the `rowID` of the detail from the list (a class that extends `ListFragment`). That information isn't available to the `FragmentActivity` class. For clarification, here's the code I use to operate the Save button. It's called from the `onCreateView` method of the Fragment class and I want to re-use this code (put it in its own method, probably) when the back button is hit.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
    Typeface danielFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "danielbk.ttf");

    final EditText notes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
    notes.setTypeface(danielFont);
    notes.setTextSize(12);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to save your Notes?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    String Notes = notes.getText().toString();
                    Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(STITCHES_URI, rowID);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("stitchnotes", Notes);
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(updateUri,values,null,null);
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //getActivity().finish();
                }
            });

    alert = builder.create();

    ImageButton savebutton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    savebutton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.show();
        }
    });
    notes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            Edited = true;

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

The `rowID` that's used when I declare `updateURI` comes from the ListFragment class like so:

```
DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_stitchdetail);
if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
     //more code
     frag.setRowID(stitchid);
}
```

`setRowID` is defined in the Fragment class:

```
public void setRowID(int row_id)
{
    rowID = row_id;
}
```

and `rowID` is a private static int in the Fragment class.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I can see.

One:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        backPressed = true;
        alert.show();
        return true; // shows you consumed the event with your implementation
    }
    // blah, blah, other code
}
```

Add the following lines to your dialog yes and no `OnClickListeners`:

```
if (backPressed){
    finish();// - to exit the Activity
}
```

Alternately, create two separate builders as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // other code

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to save your Notes?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    saveNotes();
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alertSave = builder.create();


    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    saveNotes();
                    finish();
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });

    alertBack = builder.create();

    ImageButton savebutton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    savebutton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertSave.show();
        }
    });
    // other code
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        alertBack.show();
        return true; // shows you consumed the event with your implementation
    }
    // blah, blah, other code
}        


private void saveNotes() {
    String Notes = notes.getText().toString();
    Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(STITCHES_URI, rowID);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("stitchnotes", Notes);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(updateUri,values,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Catherine, thanks for your detailed answer. I've tried both options and neither works. I've walked through the code in the debugger and when I hit the Back button, I get to either the alertBack.show() line or the backPressed = true line in the onKeyDown method. Then the debugger moves past that line to the return false I have in my else statement. Never goes to the return true in the if statement. The dialog continues to display when I hit the Save button, but I never see it when I hit the Back button. I'm missing something here, but I don't have a clue what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Also - I assumed that the if (backPressed) section you specified should come at the end of the yes and no OnClickListeners and that if I'm using that strategy, I don't need two separate builders for alertSave and alertBack. Am I right?

Comment: This now works, although I admit I'm befuddled by how. 1) I deleted the if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) section of the onKeyDown method in the FragmentActivity class. Clearly that wasn't needed; don't know what I was thinking. See my edited code above. 2) putting the code to save the contents of the EditText in a separate method wasn't working, so I just duplicated it in each onClickListener method. Finally, and this is what troubles me, I changed the final return false to return true in the Fragment's onKeyDown method. I'm pretty sure this is wrong, but don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Hmm, there is some interesting stuff going on there. I've had cases when the debugger would behave in weird ways like that. It can be helpful to put logging statements in those cases--logging statements don't (usually) lie. If you're using the if(backPressed) strategy then yes, one builder will do (or more accurately, one alert).

Comment: I'm a little confused by your new onKeyDown method--I do think you need that KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, at least if I remember correctly. Why wasn't putting the code to save the contents of the EditText in a separate method working? the code duplication is probably not ideal...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47059/discussion-between-catherine-and-melanie)

Comment: My company blocks chat. Let me put some logging statements in my code and poke around a bit. If I need to use chat, could you let me know what times you're available for chat? I could do this from home if need be; I'm on EST.

Comment: Pretty much anytime, really, other than what can loosely be considered "dinnertime" on PST.

Comment: Catherine, I think I've got it figured out, so I won't need to chat, but I REALLY appreciate your willingness to help. Your answer got me 95% there. The rest was 1) uncommenting the onKeyDown in the Fragment Activity and moving the code that dealt with the Detail Fragment onKeyDown to within that block and 2) overriding the onKeyDown method in the List Fragment also. I'm going to work on getting the code that saves the Edit Text contents to a separate method, but that's a different issue. Anyway, THANK YOU!!!