# Is Possible for on Back Pressed method with alert dialog in fragment

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


            Log.d("back button", "back button pressed");
            AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            ad1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit? ");
            ad1.setCancelable(false);

            ad1.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


            ad1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FrndsearchFragment.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


            AlertDialog alert=ad1.create();
            alert.show();

        }
```

By using the code i getting the error in  `@Override` and i write the **super.onBackPressed** i got onBackPressed in **super.onBackPressed**  .

Comment: Hi friend,can you post full method onBackPressed please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling AlertDialog.Builder in Java For Android Fragment When Back Button Is Pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615358/calling-alertdialog-builder-in-java-for-android-fragment-when-back-button-is-pre)

Comment: Hi friend,
Cannot add method onBackPressed in fragment, you should handle this method in Activity, check current fragment and handle by TAG (when you replace fragment, add TAG)

Comment: Total code should be given in above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258147/1527458

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the same by overriding `onKeyDown` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Exit");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit the application?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                exit();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void exit() {
    finish();
}
```