# How to implement a backstack when using the KitKat Transitions Framework

Tags: android, android-animation, android-4.4-kitkat, android-transitions

I am using the new KitKat [Transitions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html) API on Android. I have created two `Scene` objects using two layouts. I animate from `Scene 1` to `Scene 2` inside a `Fragment`. I want to automatically move back to the previous `Scene` when the user presses the back button.

Is there some kind of built-in backstack mechanism when using `Transitions`, or do I have to roll my own?

It is easy enough to call `TransitionManager.go(scene1)`, but I  really do not want to implement an `onBackPressed()` listener in all my fragments that have `Scene` animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own solution.

Have your `Activity` implement this

```
public interface SceneBackstackHandler {

    public void addBackstackListener(BackstackListener listener);

    public void removeBackstackListener(BackstackListener listener);

    public void removeAllBackstackListeners();

    public interface BackstackListener {
        public boolean onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
private final Object mBackstackListenerLock = new Object();
private List<BackstackListener> mBackstackListeners = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    synchronized (mBackstackListenerLock) {
        for (BackstackListener mBackstackListener : mBackstackListeners) {
            if (mBackstackListener.onBackPressed()) {
                // handled by fragment
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    removeAllBackstackListeners();
}

@Override
public void addBackstackListener(BackstackListener listener) {
    synchronized (mBackstackListenerLock) {
        mBackstackListeners.add(listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void removeBackstackListener(BackstackListener listener) {
    synchronized (mBackstackListenerLock) {
        mBackstackListeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void removeAllBackstackListeners() {
    synchronized (mBackstackListenerLock) {
        mBackstackListeners.clear();
    }
}
```

**Child Fragment:**

```
public class MySceneFragment extends Fragment
        implements SceneBackstackHandler.BackstackListener {

    private Scene mCurrentScene;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mBackstackHandler = (SceneBackstackHandler) activity;
        mBackstackHandler.addBackstackListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mBackstackHandler.removeBackstackListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        if (mCurrentScene != null && mCurrentScene.equals(mMyScene)) {
            removeMyScene();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void changeScene(Scene scene) {
        TransitionManager.go(scene);
        mCurrentScene = scene;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you storing mCurrentScene? Are you using TM.go(scene) in removeMyScene() or are you just calling .exit()?

Comment: I added that part to the sample. `mCurrentScene` is a field in `MySceneFragment`. I use `TransitionManager#go` to change what scene is showing. I don't ever "remove" a scene, only move between them.

Answer (score 1):

I use an [Otto event bus](http://square.github.io/otto/) to communicate between my `Activity` and `Fragment`s. The controlling `Activity` maintains its own `Stack` of custom back events which each contain a back action `Runnable`, i.e. what action should be taken when the back button is pressed.

The advantage to this approach is a slightly more decoupled design and should scale with more fragments. For readability, I have defined the Otto Events inside my `Fragment`, here, but these could be easily moved elsewhere in your project.

Here's some sample code to give you an idea of how it's done.

### Fragment(s)

The Fragment signals its intent to take hold of the next back press by [posting](http://square.github.io/otto/1.x/otto/com/squareup/otto/Bus.html#post-java.lang.Object-) a `BackStackRequestEvent` to the Otto event bus and supplying a `Runnable` action to be executed when the event is popped off the `Activity`'s custom stack. When the Fragment is detached, it sends a `ClearBackStackEvent` to the bus to remove any of the `Fragment`'s back actions from the activity's custom stack.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String BACK_STACK_ID = "MY_FRAGMENT";

    ...

    public class BackStackRequestEvent {
        private Runnable action;
        private String id;

        public BackStackRequestEvent(Runnable action, String id) {
            this.action = action;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void goBack() {
            action.run();
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    public class ClearBackStackEvent {
        private String id;

        public ClearBackStackEvent(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        // Get your Otto singleton and notify Activity that this
        // Fragment's back actions are no longer needed
        // The Fragment lifecycle stage in which you do this might vary
        // based on your needs
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new ClearBackStackEvent(BACK_STACK_ID));
    }

    ...

    public void someChangeInFragment() {
        // Notify the Activity that we want to intercept the next onBackPressed
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new BackStackRequestEvent(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Reverse what we did
                doBackAction();
            }
        }, BACK_STACK_ID)); // constant used later to remove items from Stack
    }
}
```

### Activity

The activity [registers](http://square.github.io/otto/1.x/otto/com/squareup/otto/Bus.html#register-java.lang.Object-) / [unregisters](http://square.github.io/otto/1.x/otto/com/squareup/otto/Bus.html#unregister-java.lang.Object-) its interest in the events we defined above in `onStart()` and `onStop()`. When it receives a new `BackStackRequestEvent` it adds it to its custom back stack. Once `onBackPressed()` is called, it pops the back stack and invokes the back action using `BackStackRequestEvent.goBack()` which in turn runs the Fragment's `Runnable`. If there is nothing on the Stack, the normal back behaviour is followed.

When the Fragment is detached, the Activity receives a `ClearBackStackEvent` and it removes all items of the supplied `id` from the Stack.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Stack<MyFragment.BackStackRequestEvent> customBackStack = new Stack<>();

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe // Annotation indicating that we want to intercept this Otto event
    public void backStackRequested(MyFragment.BackStackRequestEvent request) {
        customBackStack.push(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (customBackStack.empty()) {
            // No custom actions so default behaviour followed
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            // Pop the custom action and call its goBack() action
            MyFragment.BackStackRequestEvent back = customBackStack.pop();
            back.goBack();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void clearBackStackRequested(MyFragment.ClearBackStackEvent request) {
        String id = request.getId();
        for (MyFragment.BackStackRequestEvent backItem : customBackStack) {
            if (backItem.getId().contentEquals(id)) {
                customBackStack.remove(backItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```