# Find a view of a Fragment in the Fragment Activity

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a FragmentActivity in which a Fragment is attached. Now at a particular step in onBackPressed of the Fragment Activity, I want to change the DRAWABLE OF A BUTTON which is defined in Fragment and not in the Fragment Activity.

My Question is: How can I change the drawable of that Button (which is defined under Fragment), in my Fragment Activity's onBackPressed Method.

Thanks

Comment: @Nachi What the hell ?? Have you read the Question Carefully ???? What I am asking is how to find the view of Fragment in the FragmentActivity. It is not about the Backpressed,

Comment: Take a closer look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133522/1025599. You need to define an interface in your fragment that can be called from the parent activity. Inside the fragment you can get a reference to your view and change the drawable there.

Comment: @Gaurav check my explanation..Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

While you click back, then onBackPress Method of your attached activity will be called.

Now if you want to manipulate something in Fragment class create an Interface.

Follow this way  :->

Step 1:

```
   Activity onBackPress(){
   myinterface.changebutton()
    }
```

Step 2:

```
 public Interface myinterface{
 public void changeButton(){}
 }
```

Step 3:

```
  Fragment class implements myinterface{

  onCreateView{
  // Intialize the Button view here}

  public void changeButton(){

  mybutton.setBackgroundResource();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the fragment is **LoginFragment** having a button(public scope) **loginButton**. Then you can do something like this in your onBackPressed:

```
LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();// this is a class level variable 
// on in back pressed
fragment.loginButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher) );
```

Alternately you can have a method on your LoginFragment to change the backgroundDrawable:

```
public void changeBackGround(){
    loginButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
}
// call it like this
fragment.changeBackGround();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
       ((Button)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_id));
```