# How to close ListView's Contextual Action Mode on fragment destroy method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, ondestroy

I've succesfully implemented CAB for ListView in Fragment and everything work just fine -> but when I hit back or when I change displayed fragment through navigation drawer, CAB stays opened. What I need to do is to close CAB in onDestroy method. I've tried this:

```
listView.clearChoices();
listView.cancelLongPress();
```

But it has no effect to CAB. Any solutions here?

Answer (score 7):

I found pretty easy way how to handle this:

1) Make global variable of type ActionMode:

```
ActionMode actionMode = null;
```

2a) Assign ActionMode in onCreateActionMode() method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode, menu);
    actionMode = mode;
    return true;
}
```

2b) Also put this in onDestroyActionMode() method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    actionMode = null;
}
```

3) Override onDestroy() method (you can also use onPause() if you want to close CAB every time fragment is paused, but this may be annoying to users):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //Destroy action mode
    if(actionMode != null)
        actionMode.finish();
}
```

That's it, now every time you'll replace Fragment, it will cancel ActionMode.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it for the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    actionmode.finish(); // Replace with reference to your CAB.
}
```

You can put the same command into your button logic.

Comment: Since ListView is in fragment, there's no onBackPressed(), but you gave me an idea - gonna post it as separate answer.

Comment: Ah, good point. Some workarounds to that here, in case your idea doesn't work out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments

Comment: Look at my answer to this question, it works now :) And it's easy to use and it gives you additional option to cancel CAB at anytime you need to.