# App exit on double tab in android

Tags: android, double, exit, tap

I want to exit the app only when double tap continously. I am using fragment class. I used the below code but doesn't work

```
private long lastPressedTime;
private static final int PERIOD = 2000;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (event.getDownTime() - lastPressedTime < PERIOD) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press again to exit.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lastPressedTime = event.getEventTime();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

please guide me how to implement this in an app.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your implementation inside onKeydown and try this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Now getting this error

"The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type Fragment"

Comment: Declare onBackPressed() in your activity!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

in your activity, because activity responsible for back button handling

Look to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments) question, it has not got an accepted answer, but contain some solutions

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i(tag, "Start: On Back Pressed!");

    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        Log.i(tag, "Double Back Pressed!");

        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_exit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2500);

}
```

dont forget to add this line in onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you paste it in activity class, not in the fragment