# How to override onBackPressed() in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I want to use `onBackPressed()` in Fragment to back to its Activity when I click the back button, but I don't know how to do it. I can't override onBackPressed() in Fragment, because there isn't this methods.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Similar post solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/6831069) Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onBackPressed() in your Activity.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    YourFragment mYourFragment = (YourFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YourFragment.TAG);
    if(mYourFragment!=null){
    // Your Code
  }
```

Comment: i try,I want to click back button  to back activity from fragment, i .`addToBackStack()`  then  pop when i click,but not work

Answer (score 0):

Just override onBackButton() in your Activity. Detect if the Fragment is currently shown and detach it from your Activity. I think you can get the fragment by tag, or something like that.

Comment: I want to click back button  to back activity from fragment, i .`addToBackStack()`  then  pop when i click,but not work

Comment: Use FragmentManager.beginTransaction.remove(Fragment) instead. Note that this is NOT the correct syntax to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is a part of activity, just handle the back key in activity, manage your fragments in activity should be ok.

Comment: I want to click back button  to back activity from fragment, i .`addToBackStack()`  then  pop when i click,but not work