# How to both addtobackstack() and remove() for fragments in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've added an `addToBackStack` to a button, but when I hit the back button it goes back to the fragment it just exited, why? I've also tried to add `remove()` but that crashes the app. In an activity one can use `finish()` to do what I want, but what about in a fragment?

```
public class RateFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView title;
private RatingBar ratingBar;
private Button rateknap;
private Forslag forslag;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rod = i.inflate(R.layout.activity_rate, container, false);

    title = (TextView) rod.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) rod.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    rateknap = (Button) rod.findViewById(R.id.rateknap);
    rateknap.setOnClickListener(this);

    forslag = ((AnnonceDisplay) this.getActivity()).getForslag();
    title.setText(forslag.getTitle());


    return rod;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == rateknap) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Vil du give " + ratingBar.getRating() + " stjerner?")
                .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                launchintent();


                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }
                ).show();


    }
}

private void launchintent() {
    Fragment fragment = new AnnonceFrag();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
            .remove(this)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();


 }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.hadi.do2get, PID: 21875
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: RateFrag{1737948 #2 id=0x7f0c0069}
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1138)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1597)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1504)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:499)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2482)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2456)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2643)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2707)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3713)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
12-04 00:21:26.050 21875-21875/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The log says you have already added that fragment. replace() is the same as calling remove() and then add(). Are you calling add() or replace() anywhere else?

Comment: Similar to finish() is popBackStack()

Comment: @TylerPfaff: Yes, but in another fragment. The problem is, when I click on the backbutton it goes back to the fragment it came which it shouldn't

Comment: The log says you're trying to add RateFrag when it's already added and it's causing a crash. Is this log not correct? It doesn't sound like the app is crashing from your previous comment.

Comment: hmm it works fine when I don't write remove()

Comment: But I need to use popbackstack. How do I implement that in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24881908/629259

Comment: I've tried to add                                     getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
after my launchintent();, but it doesn't work why?