# How to call onBackPressed in MainActivity which extends Fragment in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which `MainActivity` extends Fragment. Here is I need to call `onBackPressed` for some usage. How can I achieve this?

I used below code which does not worked

```
class MainActivity extends Freagment{
.
.
.
.

Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

The previous page is just like this

```
class LoadWebData extends Activity
{
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Fragments don't have `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: may i know what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments

Comment: i need to go back when back button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

you can add the particular fragment to the backstack by  calling addToBackStack method. take a look at [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/04/allow-navigate-back-through.html) example.

```
MyDetailFragment myDetailFragment = new MyDetailFragment();
myDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.phone_container, myDetailFragment);

/*
 * Add this transaction to the back stack. 
 * This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is 
 * committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off 
 * the stack.
 */
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments do not listen to on back pressed. A common pattern I have seen used is  interacting with the fragment manager from the activity to pop fragments when on back pressed is fired.... see code below!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
final int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();

if (count == 0) {
    super.onBackPressed();
} else {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
}
```

Comment: sorry. it didnt helped me

Comment: For this to work your fragment transactions need to be added to the backstack.

Comment: please can you say how to do it?

Comment: FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
      getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myid, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();