# Going to a previous layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have two layouts and I switch to the second layout when the `ImageButton` is pressed. On my nexus 6, how do I keep the first layout running so when I'm on the second layout and press back it would show the first layout?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);

        ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(1);

        ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                setContentView(R.layout.layoutsecond);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: You can use 2 fragments for your task. Add 2nd fragment when you press a button and when you'll press back the previous fragment will automatically be shown.

Comment: As mentioned on your previous question, changing layouts like that isn't really a good idea. Use another navigation pattern - like `Fragment`s, or multiple `Activities` - where the state will be handled for you. Otherwise, you need to take care of re-initializing all of your `View`s after each layout change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General idea, though horrible advice. Best to use [Fragments and take advantage of the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

Start with a `List<Integer>`.

Store your first view on it

```
list.add(R.layout.view1);
```

Set your content view in `onCreate` and increment the position of the layout you are at.

```
int position = 0; // make this a field variable 
setContentView(list.get(position++));
```

Increment and add more layout IDs when you call `setContentView` again.

```
list.add(R.layout.view2);
setContentView(list.get(position++));
```

Implement `onBackPressed` to go back. Be careful about out of bounds exceptions, though.

```
setContentView(list.get(--position));
```

If you want to implement a feature to go forward, then

```
setContentView(list.get(++position));
```