# How do handle onBackPressed() in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

This is my class name

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment implements OnRestartRequest {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mCardStackLayout.isCardSelected()) {
            mCardStackLayout.restoreCards();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Error on this line: `super.onBackPressed();`

I don't know what's the problem in fragment class's on back pressed button.

Comment: Check this post-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments?rq=1

Comment: Please, read carefully http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Reading the error messages would have helped you. :)

Comment: Hello, my answer it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments/46425415#46425415) 
Hop it help

Answer (score 6):

There is no `onBackPressed()` method in `Fragment`. You can do something like calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()` from your `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3):

Fragment does not have `onBackPress()` method as we have for activity. I prefer handling back press using below code, Hope it help you:

```
 private void handleBackPress(View view) {


        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
            {
                if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
                {

                    cancelCountDownTimerAndSaveValues();

                    if (Constants.Fragments.CurrentFragment != null)
                    {
                         getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } );
    }
```

and here view is your main view for fragment as you get from

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxxx, container, false);`

Answer (score 1):

You should call `getActivity()` from inside you fragment like this:

```
getActivity().onBackedPressed();
```

Note: watch that you import the right `getActivity()`, If you use  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` you need to import the correct package.

Answer (score 0):

Fragmetns doesn't have their own `OnBackPressed` and you have to handle their transaction from its parent Actvitiy which contains that fragment.

Example: // in Parent Activity on Fragmetn

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // This will get you total fragment in the backStack
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    switch(count){
        case 0:
            super.onBackPressed();
            break;
        case 1:
            // handle back press of fragment one
            break;
        case 2:
            // and so on for fragment 2 etc
            break;
        default:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
    }
}
```