# Separate Back Navigation for a Tabbed View Pager in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

**What I want.**

In a tab sliding menu context, I want to replace a fragment to another inside a tab, and maintaining the tab menu, and also the current tab. When sliding to another tab and returning to original, I want the last fragment to be displayed.

For example, I have `tab_a` with `Fragment_1`, `tab_b` with `Fragment_4` and `tab_c` with `Fragment_7`. Now I want a button in `Fragment_1` that opens me `Fragment_2`, but I want to be able to swipe to the fragments of the `tab_b` and `tab_c`. And when I return to tab_a, `Fragment_2` must be displayed.

[image]

```
MainActivity
    |
    |
ContainerFragment
    |
    |
    |_ _ _ Tab A
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 1
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 2
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 3
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ ...
    |        
    |_ _ _ Tab B
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 4
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 5
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 6
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ ...
    |
    |_ _ _ Tab C
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 7
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 8
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ Fragment 8
    |        |
    |        |_ _ _ ...
```

**My current main activity.**

Xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private final static int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_a,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_b,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_c
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment1());
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment4());
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment7());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragments**

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="myContext">

    <Button
        android:text="Go to next Fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_nextFrag" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private void goNextFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.tab1_container, new Fragment2());
        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment.
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        // Go to next Fragment Button.
        final Button nextFrag = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_nextFrag);
        nextFrag .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goNextFragment();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Edit:

I've got some solutions, but none is perfect. If I put a Framelayaout in MainActivity, `Fragment_1` is correctly replaced to `Fragment_2`, but it is also in `tab_b` and `tab_c`. If the FrameLayout is in `Fragment_1`, I can swipe the other tabs correctly, but the replacement goes not good, cause `Fragment_2` is opened, but `Fragment_1` is also there.

Comment: What exactly happens in your case? Does the screen orientation repopulates all the fragments at initial state?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I havn't reached that point yet, I'm still working in replace fragments correctly. I have seen another solutions, and some consist in a big switch for each fragment possible, but if we consider a big scenario with a lot of fragments, this solution can't be the best one, and I am sure there has to be a better solution.

Comment: @SantiGil you mean you want something like Flipboard app? tabs inside tabs?

Comment: @Amir I explain it a bit better. I currently have 3 tabs with one fragment each one (`Fragment1`, `Fragment4` and `Fragment7` respectively). Now I want a button in the `tab_a`, for example, which opens `Fragment2`, and maintains the tab order. If I swipe to `tab_b`, and return to `tab_a`, I want `Fragment2` to be displayed. And I want also to be able to go back from `Fragment2` to `Fragment1`.

Comment: Edited question with more information of my problem.

Comment: I wrote a blog article on that topic a few months ago: https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4#.s0jiyd6gu :)

Comment: @mcwise Worked! And in a very smart way, +1. How would you implement with this code a method that "kills" the two previous fragments in a tab? I want to give you the bounty.

Comment: I just posted an answer! :) If you mean you want to pop the backstack twice, you could fire the back button event a second time as a hack: `this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ViewPager` together with a `TabLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a class that extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to initialize the `ViewPager` with your initial `Fragment`s:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Fragment 1");
        add("Fragment 4");
        add("Fragment 7");
    }};

    private List<Fragment> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        initializeTabs();
    }

    private void initializeTabs() {
        tabs.add(HostFragment.newInstance(new Fragment1()));
        tabs.add(HostFragment.newInstance(new Fragment4()));
        tabs.add(HostFragment.newInstance(new Fragment7()));
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

The fragments containing the actual contents should be wrapped by a `HostFragment`, that uses its child `FragmentManager` to replace the current fragment with a new one if you want to navigate, or to pop the last fragment from the fragment stack. Call its `replaceFragment` to navigate:

```
public class HostFragment extends BackStackFragment {
    private Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.host_fragment, container, false);
        if (fragment != null) {
            replaceFragment(fragment, false);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
        if (addToBackstack) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public static HostFragment newInstance(Fragment fragment) {
        HostFragment hostFragment = new HostFragment();
        hostFragment.fragment = fragment;
        return hostFragment;
    }
}
```

The HostFragment should extend the abstract class `BackstackFragment`

```
public abstract class BackStackFragment extends Fragment {
    public static boolean handleBackPressed(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        if(fm.getFragments() != null){
            for(Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()){
                if(frag != null && frag.isVisible() && frag instanceof BackStackFragment){
                    if(((BackStackFragment)frag).onBackPressed()){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean onBackPressed()
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        if(handleBackPressed(fm)){
            return true;
        } else if(getUserVisibleHint() && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            fm.popBackStack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Wire everthing up in the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // 2 is enough for us; increase if you have more tabs!
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(!BackStackFragment.handleBackPressed(getSupportFragmentManager())){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void openNextFragment() {
        HostFragment hostFragment = (HostFragment) customPagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        // your logic to change the fragments...
    }
}
```

This solution is certainly not perfect but gets the job done. Read more fluff about it in my [blog post](https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4) on the issue.

Comment: Perfect! I [added this](https://gyazo.com/8f55aeb51323113b093ad5c6e40ba2a7) to do `openNextFragment` more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you explained I Implement following:

1- In your Activity create your `Tabs` and `ViewPager`:

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    PagerAdapter mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getContext());
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //tab.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
```

2- In each Tabs create `ViewPager` (I assume you want tabs inside `tabs` if you don't need tabs just removed them), Implementation of each `fragment` would be something like :

```
    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vp_pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    CategoryAdapter mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());//make sure this ChildFragmentManager
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Also in fragment create a Button which when Click goes to another fragment:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1); // go to second fragment
            }
        });
```

final result would be something like following and when If you go to *Home* Tabs and then goes back to *Category* Tab you're your `Fragment` position not changed.

Two point you should remember:

1. set `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` if you don't want to destroy your fragment
2. In inner fragment pass `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `FragmentManager()`

[image]

If you don't need Inner `ViewPager` And you Just want load one instance of Fragment at time here is another option:

1- Do first item of previous way.

2- In your fragment xml put FrameContainer and load your fragment inside it:

```
 CategoryResultFragment f = CategoryResultFragment.newInstance();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_result_container, f)
                .commit();
```

**Edit:** This is not best approach but I think solve your issue:

1- Create a static field in your `MainActivity` like following:

```
static String[] type = new String[3];
```

2- When you call onClick in your fragment, update `String` value in your `MainActivity`.

```
public static update currentType(int pos,String type);
```

first value is ViewPager position, Second value is your inner Fragment type (e.g: fragment_d);

3- In your ViewPager

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // first tab
                    if(type[position] == "fragment_d")
                        return new Fragment_D();
                    else
                        return new Fragment_B();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I am trying your solution. The first `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` I guess that is because I have 3 tabs `tab_a` `tab_b` `tab_c`. But the second one,  why is also 3?

Comment: @SantiGil I assume your inner ViewPager have 3 pages. ( also by default setOffscreenPageLimit is 3 )

Comment: Ok! Should I have a `root fragment` for each tab, inside its viewpager I put my 3 fragments? This would be a total of 4 fragments. 1 `root fragment` and 3 `normal fragments`

Comment: let me put some simple example in github may be it's better.

Comment: Ok! In each tab I just want one instance of Fragment at time. And when I click `button`, I want to load next Fragment (the second way you suggest)

Comment: @SantiGil https://github.com/AmirHadifar/InnerTabsExample this repository may gives you some Idea.

Comment: Umm, but I don't still know how to open another fragment, not sliding the screen. In your code example, imagine that inside `Tab0 > Inner Tabs0` there is a button to open a different fragment. How would be that?

Comment: @SantiGil I set **todo** in CategoryFramgent you should setCurrentPager in OnClickListener.

Comment: But if the fragment to open is not one in the viewpager? Just another

Comment: @SantiGil by this code it's not possible ( you need add some hack to do this)

Comment: How would be the code for what I'm trying? Still don't work :I

Comment: @SantiGil what have you trying so far ?

Comment: For example, I have `tab_a` with `Fragment_1`, `tab_b` with `Fragment`_4 and `tab_c` with `Fragment_7`. Now I want a button in `Fragment_1` that opens me `Fragment_2`, but I want to be able to swipe to the fragments of the `tab_b` and `tab_c`. And when I return to `tab_a`, `Fragment_2` must be displayed.

Comment: In fragment_1 put a FrameLayout and add fragment with code like:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, SimpleFragment.newInstance())
                        .commit();

Comment: @SantiGil Also for handling backPressed in inner fragment do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29166971/1462770

Comment: Now I have a Button and FrameLayout in my `Fragment_1`. If i click the button, `Fragment_2` is opened and i can swipe the others `tabs` correctly; but button from `Fragment_1` is still there, in `tab_a`.

Comment: @SantiGil it's not standard guideline So you should handle it with some hacks.

Comment: @SantiGil update my code a bit. it's kind of hacky but I think solve your issue.

Comment: Done, but now button doesn't open new Fragment_2. **1.** In MainActivity `static int tab1Fragment = R.id.fragment_1;` and `public static void update (int newFragment) { tab1Fragment = newFragment; }`. **2.** In Fragment_1 `MainActivity.update(R.id.fragment_2r);` in the onClick. **3.** And in ViewPager [this code](https://gyazo.com/cd0622094c60f9638396a9d2e26f8647).

Answer (score 0):

You can change fragments inside page fragment. For example, TAB_A implements logic of picking fragment 1 or 2, and displaying picked fragment inside. 
Hierarchy looks like:

ViewPager -> TAB_A -> fragment 1 or 2 (displaying inside TAB_A).

Also you should use getChildFragmentManager() to manage fragments inside TAB_A.