# set OnBackPressed in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am having 4 fragments.They are consists of HomeFragment, Rainfall, rainday, and yieldFragment.
If right now i am on Rainfall fragment, then i press backbutton, 
i want the fragment will come back to Home fragment(as a default). 
But right now my applicaton situation is when press backbutton, 
the application was closed. I've tried by using onBackpressed, but i think my onBackPressed was not work properly.

What should i do for this situation..?Please anyone can answer.
i've tried this...

```
  public void onBackPressed() {

        fragment=new HomeFragment();}
```

Please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: You can override onBackPressed() in it's parent Activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Comment: Similar problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/6831069) Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, all you have to do is paste the following line of code into the onViewCreated fun of the relevant fragment.

```
        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                "your_code_here"
                "If you leave this blank, the back button will not work."
            }
        }

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

- first of all at the time of switch in to fragment ,used **#replace**
  rather then **#add** new fragment from your container activity.
- second inside your **#inner fragments** ,override onResume() as depicted
  below. It will give you call back of device back button .

  @Override
      public void onResume() {

  ```
      super.onResume();

      getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      getView().requestFocus();
      getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

              if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                  HomeFragment fragObj = new HomeFragment();

                  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragObj)
                          .commit();

                  return true;
              }

              return false;
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: can i ask you what the refer of (R.id.fragment_container)? :)

Comment: R.id.fragment_container ,is the id of your container activity (main activity / home activity )in which all fragments will be loaded.Normally we used frameLayout as a container in side main activity and this id refers that frameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add your fragment transaction to the back stack, like so:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.your_fragment_id, RainfallFragment())
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit()
```

If you're extending AppCompatActivity and using the latest version of support library, you don't have to do anything else. But if that's not the case, override onBackPressed() in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
     } else {
           finish();
     }
}
```