# How to stop the edittext to change the focus on the click of the back button in fragment?

Tags: android, android-edittext, back-button, keyevent

I want to clear the focus of the edittext when the user clicks on the back button.

This is my onResume method :-

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == keyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    mEdtDob.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

    }
```

I want to do that when i click on the back button the focus of the edittext should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Code is correct. Check is **parent view of EditText** clickable? If it is not, after removing focus, EditText may gain focus again.

Add this line to **parent view of EditText** in xml:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: dude ! i am using fragment not an activity

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
int count =    getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); 
if (count == 0) { 
super.onBackPressed();
mEdtDob.clearFocus();
//additional code 
} else       {     getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
} }
```

check this link:

[How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

just add these two lines inside onKey Method.Code:

```
mEdtDob.setFocusable(true);
mEdtDob.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

if this is nt working let me know in comments....