# Android implementing onBackPress on Fragment cause of disable exit from application

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application i have some fragment and i can exit from application by click on back on phone without problem, but when i implementing `onBackPress` on that i can't exit from application

My code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (getView() == null) {
        return;
    }
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (slider_call_phones.isOpened()) {
                    slider_call_phones.closeLayer(true);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to handle `onBackPressed` on fragment not Activities

Comment: This code is not implementing `onBackPressed()`. If you get rid of this code and instead implement `onBackPressed()`, you may have better luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Comment: @CommonsWare you mean is `onBackPressed` work fine on Fragments ?

Comment: There is no `onBackPressed()` on `Fragment`. IMHO, the decision of what to do when BACK is pressed is the responsibility of the activity, not any particular fragment. And, there is an `onBackPressed()` method on `Activity`.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I want to handle `onBackPressed` on fragment not Activities

Comment: @CommonsWare yes i know that, on fragment i have some slider and with your solution i have to define more and more listener to handle them

Comment: The BACK button is for large-scale navigation (e.g., exiting an activity, reversing a `FragmentTransaction`) or system UI (e.g., exiting a dialog, collapsing the soft keyboard). I do not know what your "slider" is, but I suspect that I would not recommend that it take control over the BACK button.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes you're right, ok, then i handle that inside parent Activity, Thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it,

- create an interface that would receive `onBackPressed()` in any class
  that implements it and would return true if it's handling the method or false otherwise. This would make sure that your app would exit when your return false.
- create a stack of these interfaces in your `Activity`, then add any of such interfaces to it.
- override `onBackPressed()` in your activity, then anytime it's called, get a listener from the stack and call its own `onBackPressed()` if it returns true. If it returns false, then it's not handling `onBackPressed()` so Activity can take over and remove fragment or exit the application.

Here's a sample implementation.

**In your Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

//a stack of OnBackPressedListeners, stack one when you want it to receive onBackPressed() from
//this activity.
//PS used stack so that by LIFO, the last listener would be the first to be called.
private Stack<OnBackPressedListener> onBackPressedListeners = new Stack<>();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!onBackPressedListeners.isEmpty()) {
        if (onBackPressedListeners.peek().onBackPressed()) //if interface is handling onBackPressed(), return. Otherwise super would be called below.
            return;
    }

    //if no listeners, then do super. This would ensure natural behaviour such as closing the app or popping a fragment when no listeners are using onBackPressed()
    super.onBackPressed();
}

//listener interface
public static interface OnBackPressedListener {

    /**
     * @return true if you're handling onBackPressed, false otherwise to let super.onBackPressed() take over
     */
    public boolean onBackPressed();
}

public void addOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener listener) {
    onBackPressedListeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener listener) {
    onBackPressedListeners.remove(listener);
}

}
```

**In your Fragment**

```
//implement OnBackPressedListener in your fragment.
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressedListener {


    //find somewhere to add the listener to your Activity, most likely in onCreateView(...)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).addOnBackPressedListener(this);

        ...

        return view;
    }

    //overide onBackPressed(), then return true if you're handling the onBackPressed(), false otherwise.
    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        if (slider_call_phones.isOpened()) {
            slider_call_phones.closeLayer(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //lastly remember to remove the listener when your fragment is destroyed, so that it stops receiving callbacks,
    //if you don't do this, you might get a NullPointerException.
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).removeOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }
}
```

I mostly use a single `Activity` and a whole lot of `Fragment`'s in my Android apps, this is exactly how I solve such problems you are having, for example closing a drawer in a Fragment if its open when the back button is pressed, or exiting the application if it's closed.

Answer (score -1):

You should call onBackPressed() in the following manner in order to exit from the app:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
   finishAffinity();
}
```