# Android Navigation Drawer: open deep fragment from notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

first sorry for my rusty English !

This is a doubt I have had for some time now and although my skills on Android have been getting better I haven't found an elegant solution for this issue:

Lets say an application uses the Navigation Drawer pattern and has three levels of navigation:
Home -> Posts -> Post details

When I open the App from the launcher I add the Home Fragment. From here the user can navigate all the way down to a given "post" using fragment transactions.

Now imagine there is some kind of notification that is letting me know something happened on a specific post: How would you create a "synthetic" back-stack when opening the app from the notification ? What I mean is:

1- Open the app from the notification

2- The app opens on Post Details

3- Back navigation has to be > Posts > Home

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

without any line of code its hard to say how you are setting these `Fragment`s , but you may need [addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) method or consider `@Override` [onBackPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments) properly. assuming notification is yours you can set id or whatever you need inside `PendingIntent` extras `Bundle`, obtain inside `OnCreate` method and then create a stack

Comment: yes, that is how I have solved it in the past. But I don't think it's elegant. The reason why I didn't put any code is because is more a conceptual problem I'm facing.

Comment: Look at:
https://medium.com/google-developers/tasks-and-the-back-stack-dbb7c3b0f6d4

There is a section that explains how to use ** TaskStackBuilder**. I would like to know if there is something similar for fragments.

Comment: yes, its `FragmentManager`, and the stack is set using `FragmentTransaction`. and these methods are described in `The Back Stack and Fragments` section...

Comment: So, it's not a terrible practice to add more than one transaction to the backstack before a commit ? Thanks !