# overriding back method in fragment class in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

how to quit the app whenever i press the back button from certain fragments.I found out that system.exit(1) closes the app. but i could now override method for handling back key.Is there any method to override back key ? if yes How can i perform it?

Comment: No, but what can you do is overRide onBack in activity and, make condition accordingly

Comment: actually i have about 7 fragments all under 1 activity and i only need to quit app from 1 fragment class..

Comment: You are using tabs?? in activity??

Comment: Are you using viewpager for setting fragments?

Comment: can you show how you are opening a fragment

Comment: i am using master/detail flow which has 1 activity. and i am using fragment transaction for managing layouts and handling other activities.

Comment: in activity i used following codes to replace fragments.

Comment: AddFriends fragment=new AddFriends();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack("c");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Try removing addToBackStack('c') and check what is the result?

Comment: @YogeshGautam check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in following way.

1. First make a class with static integer variable(say a).
2. Override back methods on mainActivity and choose the fragment you want to open on back pressed as per the value on static variable.
   [note:whenever new fragments are opened update static variable with new value and according to this value override back method on main activity]

Answer (score 0):

onBackPressed() function in activity will help

Comment: this should be in comments

Comment: i cannnot able to comment

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have only one activity and about 7 fragments and i only need to quit from  1 fragments...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments this answer will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is when you add a fragment add a tag with it, like

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, "My_Tag");
```

And then in activity `onBackPressed()`

```
fragment= (AddFriends)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("My_Tag");
if (fragment!= null && fragment.isVisible()) {
   //Exit from your app here
   finish();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i got an error on back pressed in line 1 showing inconvertible type. i had assummed that  MyFragment in above code means the fragment that should be override on back press...

Comment: @YogeshGautam I dont know about your code but what you shared in comments from that i suggest changing `MyFragment` with your fragment

Answer (score 0):

write this in your onBackPressed()

```
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        if (isPressed) {
            finish();
        } else {
            StringUtils.displayToastShort(this, "press again to exit");
            isPressed = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for opening a fragment

```
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment)
{

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransac‌​tion();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

and when you want to open a fragment call this function like this

```
openFragment(new AddFriends());
```

Using above function it will exit the app with back button press.